# hash_map not working

Tags: c++, hashmap

```
#include <ext/hash_map>

using namespace std;

class hash_t : public __gnu_cxx::hash_map<const char*, list<time_t> > { };
hash_t hash;

...
```

I'm having some problems using this hash_map. The const char* im using as a key is always a 12 length number with this format 58412xxxxxxx. I know there are 483809 different numbers, so that should be the hash_map size after inserting everything, but i'm only getting 193 entries.

```
hash_t::iterator it = hash.find(origen.c_str());
if (it != hash.end()) { //Found

    x++;
    (*it).second.push_front(fecha);         
}
else { //Not found

    y++;
    list<time_t> lista(1, fecha);
    hash.insert(make_pair(origen.c_str(), lista));          
}
```

The same procedure works perfectly using python dictionaries (i'm getting the correct number of entries) but not even close using c++. Is it possible that since every key begins with 58412 (actually almost every key, but not all of them, and that's the reason I don't want to chop those 5 chars), im getting a lot of collisions?

Comment: We're not in Python anymore, Toto.

Comment: Changed a couple of lines and got it working with tr1::unordered_map

Answer (score 4):

`const char*` is not good for a key, since you now have pointer comparison instead of string comparison (also, you probably have dangling pointers, the return value of `c_str()` is not usable long-term).

Use `hash_map<std::string, list<time_t> >` instead.

Comment: And what would be a good key? Would a normal string be ok if I use, for example, boost::unordered_map?

Comment: When I try to use string directly it won't compile. That's the reason I went for const char*

Comment: @Alex So oncoe it doesn't compile you choose a completely different approach instead of making it compile? Why does it not compile? Can it be there is no appropriate hash function for `std::string`?

Comment: @Alex: `unordered_map<string, list<time_t> >` should work very well.

Answer (score 1):

If your key is `char*`, you are comparing no the strings, but pointers, which makes your hashmap work differently than what you expect.  Consider using `const std::string` for the keys, so they are compared using lexicographical ordering

Comment: Ok. I get it. Any suggestion on how to go around this issue?

Comment: When I use strings as key, it wont compile. That's the reason I went for char* on the first place

Comment: Check out [these](http://forums.devshed.com/c-programming-42/tip-about-stl-hash-map-and-string-55093.html) [links](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2002-04/msg00107.html) on why the `hash_map<>` is not working with `string`s and how to fix the problem